How to update variables on a device side class?
I've defined an array class which I'd like to live on the device. I have a factory method to return a device instance of the class.
class MyArray{
private:
  int* data_ = nullptr;
  size_t width_ = 0;
  size_t height_ = 0;
  size_t pitch_ = 0;

  MyArray(size_t width, size_t height) : width_(width), height_(height){
    cudaCheckError(cudaMallocPitch(&data_, &pitch_, width_*sizeof(int), height_));
  }

public:
  __host__ __static__ MyArray* MakeInstance(size_t width, size_t height){
    MyArray h_array(width, height);

    //Allocate memory for the device object
    MyArray* d_array;
    cudaCheckError(cudaMalloc(&d_array, sizeof(MyArray)));

    // Copy the host object to the device
    cudaCheckError(cudaMemcpy(d_array, &h_array, sizeof(MyArray), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    return d_array;
  }  

I want to write setter functions for the width_ and height_ variables from the host. My question is how do I update the width_ and height_ variables from the host? Do I need to do a cudaMemcpy? Or can I just set them to a new value directly?

Allocating single objects on the device-side is usually a bad idea. It is almost always better to have the object on the host-side and only larger arrays such as the data_ member on the device side. It makes more sense to have a simple struct with the pointer and sizes that can be passed to kernels by value as a parameter. Those are accessed through the constant cache that is far more efficient than global memory access

Adding to what @Homer512 commented, you could use cuda::std::mdspan which comes with the CUDA Toolkit. It allows passing the buffer and dimensions as a single object which is separated from allocation (separation of concerns).

You have a couple of options:

Use cudaMemcpy or cudaMemcpyAsync in your setters.
Allocate object using cudaMallocManaged, which allows you to access it and set them to a new value directly from the host.
Use host page-locked memory (using cudaHostAlloc), which can be accessed directly by the host and the device.

The best option from a performance point of view depends on your use case. You can refer to this blogpost from NVIDIA's developer blog for more information.
Note that, to use cudaMallocManaged, managed memory must be supported. You can verify this using cudaDeviceGetAttribute on attribute cudaDevAttrManagedMemory. Also, for completion, on systems where ATS is enabled (you can check with attribute cudaDevAttrPageableMemoryAccessUsesHostPageTables), you can access device memory directly from the host as well (similarly to managed allocations).
